# DTX: Avoid preamble for non-latex files?

Tags: dtx

When generating files with the docstrip utility, it adds a preamble of `%`-commented lines. This easily violates the syntax of output files, if they are not latex formats.

E.g. running `pdftex` on the file `minimal.dtx` (see below), will produce a syntactically incorrect skeleton starting with

```
%%
%% This is file `minimal.py',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%% ...
...
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `minimal.py'.
```

### minimal.dtx

```
%\iffalse -- Ignore driver section when typesetting.
%<*driver>
\iffalse ---- SINGLE-FILE: INS FILE INCLUDED ---- \fi
\begingroup\input{docstrip}
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.py}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{python}}
}
\endgroup
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
$</driver>
%\fi
%
%
% \section{Imports}
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*python>
import sys
import os
%</python>
%    \end{macrocode}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use the `\nopreamble` and `\nopostamble` commands before invoking `\generate`, which suppress this output.

If the output file is sensitive to empty lines at the beginning of the file, it is additionally important to properly comment out *all* empty lines, that are not delimited by docstrip tags (`%<tag>` or `%<*tag>...%</tag>`).

See [docstrip.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/docstrip.pdf) on CTAN for details.